The Flutter device daemon cannot be started. Please check your configuration and restart the IDE
Today, I downloaded the latest version of Flutter, i.e. version 3.24.1, from Flutter's website and extracted it.
After that I faced this problem:

The Flutter device daemon cannot be started. Please check your
configuration and restart the IDE. You may need to increase the
maximum number of file handles available globally.

I read some articles on the Internet and stackoverflow, but all of them were useless and did not work for me
Note:
Maybe this is a bug in this version of flutter and another version of flutter will be released soon in which this problem has been fixed.
